# Adding Redis Caching on Duende IdentityServer 6

Tags: asp.net-core, caching, redis, duende-identity-server

What is the optimized way of caching data using redis in duende identity server 6?

I have already added redis cache on my duende identity server.
Installed ***Microsoft.Extensions.Caching.StackExchangeRedis*** package then Added as a service in the startup file.

```
builder.Services.AddStackExchangeRedisCache(options => options.Configuration = "localhost:8088");
```

Then Injected as a dependency in the login file and used setString/getString method to store and retrive the data.

```
await _distributedCache.SetStringAsync(key, value);
```

```
 string? cachedMember = await _distributedCache.GetStringAsync(key);
```

Is there any downside of doing caching in that way? Is there any better apparoach?